# Storing hex in QBytearray, extracting it and converting it to decimal

Tags: c++, qt, hex, decimal, qbytearray

```
int dd = 0xA5;

QByteArray p;
p.push_back (0xA5);
qDebug () << "SOP: " << (int)p[0];
```

This results in -91 whereas 0xA5 stands for 165 in decimal.

How to store hex in QBytearray, extract it and convert it to decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-91` is just a representation of a char value.
char has a range of `--127..127`. You are storing the value `165`, which is larger than `127`.

However, `unsigned char` has a range of `0..255`. So in this case you may read your value as an `unsigned char`:

```
qDebug() << "SOP: " << (unsigned char)p[0];
```

In addition you may use `QString` to display the corresponding hex value:

```
QString hex = QString("%1").arg((unsigned char)p[0] , 0, 16);
qDebug() << "Hex: " << hex;
```